# Нужна помощь с простым шифрованием AES256

Tags: python, криптография, шифрование

В общем у меня есть нужда зашифровать строчку простым способом, так-как я в python новичок я не очень разбираюсь в сложных темах - можете пожалуйста объяснять попроще.
Сделать я хочу так:

```
a = input("Текст")
b = input("Пароль")
c = encrypt(a, b)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Шифрование/дешифрование AES 256 с использованием библиотеки pycrypto
 
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
 
BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
 
password = input("Введите пароль шифрования: ")
 
 
def encrypt(raw, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    raw = pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
 
 
def decrypt(enc, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))
 
 
# Сначала зашифровать секретное сообщение
encrypted = encrypt("Это секретное послание", password)
print(encrypted)
 
# Давайте расшифруем с помощью нашего оригинального пароля
decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password)
print(bytes.decode(decrypted))
```

Вот [документация](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: если вас всё устраивает отметьте мой ответ как решение

Comment: У меня ещё проблема появилась
https://pastebin.com/pjM82MrA