# Ошибка при шифровании AES256

Tags: python, криптография, шифрование

Как исправить ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    encrypted = encrypt(str(data), str(password))
  File "main.py", line 14, in encrypt
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cbc.py", line 178, in encrypt
    c_uint8_ptr(plaintext),
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py", line 144, in c_uint8_ptr
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

Код:

```
import qrcode
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random


BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]


def encrypt(raw, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    raw = pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
 
 
def decrypt(enc, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))
print("CryptQR v1")
print("==============================================")
while True:
  lang = input("Choose the language - 1)Russian  2)English: ")
  if (lang == "1"): 
    a = input("Выберите режим - 1)Создание QR  2)Открытие QR: ")
    if (a == "1"): # Создание QR режим - QR Creating Mode
      while True:
        data = input ("Введите текст (до 512 символов): ")
        if (len(data) > 512):
          print("==============================================")
          print("Вы не можете ввести больше 512 символов!")
          print("==============================================")
          continue
        else:
          while True:
            password = input ("Введите пароль (От 16 символов): ")
            if (len(password) < 16):
              print("==============================================")
              print("Вы не можете ввести меньше 16 символов!")
              print("==============================================")
              continue
            else:
              encrypted = encrypt(str(data), str(password))
              filename = "cryptqr.png"
              img = qrcode.make(str(encrypted))
              img.save(filename)
              print("==============================================")
              print("QR-код создан!")
              print("==============================================")
              break
          break
    break
  elif (lang == "2"): # Часть на наглийском - English part
    a = input("Choose mode - 1)Create QR  2)Open QR: ")
    if (a == "1"): # Создание QR режима - QR Creating Mode
      while True:
        data = input ("Enter text (up to 512 characters): ")
        if (len(data) > 512):
          print("==============================================")
          print("You cannot enter more than 512 characters!")
          print("==============================================")
          continue
        else:
          while True:
            password = input ("Enter password (From 16 characters):")
            if (len(password) < 16):
              print("==============================================")
              print("You cannot enter less than 16 characters!")
              print("==============================================")
              continue
            else:
              encrypted = encrypt(str(data), str(password))
              filename = "cryptqr.png"
              img = qrcode.make(str(encrypted))
              img.save(filename)
              print("==============================================")
              print("QR code created successfully!")
              print("==============================================")
              break
          break
    break
  else:
    continue
```

Подскажите, что делать?

PS Связанный вопрос: [Нужна помощь с простым шифрованием AES256](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1235537/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-aes256/1235563?noredirect=1#comment2166842_1235563)

Comment: Код-то Ваш приведите. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, ссылаться на другое как на основной источник - дурной тон.

Comment: по "ссылке на код" в 46-й строке нет ```encrypted = encrypt(str(data), str(password))```, добавьте корректный код, который вызывает данную ошибку

Comment: Исправил - теперь правильно

Comment: вы дебажили код в предыдущем ответе? он нерабочий (def encrypt())

Answer (score 1):

1. Я догадался, что вы используете pyCryptodome, но Вам следовало указать, какими сторонними библиотеками вы пользуетесь.
2. Ваша функция `encrypt` передаёт параметр `raw` в метод `cipher.encrypt` как есть.
3. Метод `cipher.encrypt`, как [написано в документации](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/cipher.html#api-principles), работает только с байтами:

> Plaintexts and ciphertexts (input/output) can only be bytes, bytearray or memoryview. In Python 3, you cannot pass strings.

4. Вы же в функцию `encrypt` передаёте `str(data)`

Вам нужно превратить данные в байты. Например, `str(data).encode("utf-8")`

Comment: TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Comment: @IvanGorincih, я, безусловно, провидец и способен прозревать сквозь времена и пространства. Вот прямо сейчас взял и прозрел, что у вас проблемы с функцией `pad`, то изучайте матчасть Python, как работать с байтовыми строками.

Comment: И ещё. Таки моё прозрение подсказывает, что @videx дал вам решение для Python 2, а вы пытаетесь его запустить под Python 3. Учите матчасть, право слово.