# Подскажите с шифрованием в aes-256 на python

Tags: python, криптография, python-3.9

Поделитесь пожалуйста кодом для шифрования (дешифрования) в aes-256 на python.
В шифровании совсем не шарю. Установил библиотеку `pycryptodome` и юзаю `python 3.9.1`.
Заранее всем спасибо.
Я видел похожие вопросы на форумах, но они мне не помогли. И когда я пытаюсь использовать код (из этого [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1235537/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-aes256/1235563#1235563)) выдает ошибку:

```
Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

Comment: А зачем лезете, раз не "шарите" и не хотите сами разбираться?

Comment: Лезу потому что столкнулся с ситуацией где нужно шифрование. Сам пробовал разбираться, но ничего не получилось, и решил спросить у тех кто шарит в этом.

Comment: Вам нужно не шифрование изучать, а [преобразование строк в байты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3). Сообщение об ошибке вам именно об этом говорит - вы передаёте строку, а шифрование умеет работать только с байтами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тоже не сильно вникал в криптографию но на сайте есть простой рабочий [пример](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html).
После минимальных правок получаем:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

data = b"Hello world"
key = get_random_bytes(16) # Генерируем ключ шифрования

# Шифрование
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)
nonce = cipher.nonce
print(ciphertext) # Зашифрованный текст

# Дешифровка
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
data = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
print(data)
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно адаптировать код, если я хочу брать текст от функции `input()`
Если я меняю на `input()` выдает ошибку ```Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code```

Comment: Можно так `data = input().encode()`

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, но не могли бы вы разъяснить, зачем вам режим EAX? Вам настолько необходимо гарантировать целостность шифртекста? При таком режиме у вас на выходе не один шифртекст, но шифртекст + MAC tag для проверки целостности. ИМХО, для топикстартера это излишне, [режима CBC](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html) вполне достаточно.

Comment: @Pak Uula Как писал выше это просто немного адаптированный пример. В СВС если не ошибаюсь надо передавать еше и iv. Если ошибаюсь предложите вариант ответа )